Good way to connect all events of a class to their appropriate handlers
My program consists of a mainwindow and other screens that pop up on request. Different screens do different things, so they all define different EVENTs that can be invoked on button click. All screens inherit from a base class called SCREEN. All screens have one EVENT in common, which is "ReturnRequest".
This is how it looks:
public class Screen
{
    public virtual event Action ReturnRequest;  

    public Screen()
    { }
}

public class MainMenuScreen : Screen
{
    public override event Action ReturnRequest;
    public event Action ExitRequest;
    public event Action NewGameRequest;
    public event Action LoadRequest;
    public event Action SaveRequest;

    public MainMenuScreen(){}
}

public class DeathScreen : Screen
{
    public override event Action ReturnRequest;
    public event Action ExitRequest;

    public DeathScreen(){}
}

The main logic of the program connects the events of different screens to their handlers, like this:
public void ConnectAllScreenEvents(Screen screen)
  {
      screen.ReturnRequest += ReturnFromScreen;

      if (screen.GetType() == typeof(MainMenuScreen))
      {
          MainMenuScreen _screen = screen as MainMenuScreen;
          _screen.ExitRequest += Exit;
          _screen.LoadRequest += DeSerializeGame;
          _screen.NewGameRequest += NewGame;
          _screen.SaveRequest += SerializeGame;
      }
      else if (screen.GetType() == typeof(DeathScreen))
      {
          DeathScreen _screen = screen as DeathScreen;
          _screen.ExitRequest += Exit;
      }

Disconnection works the same way.
This code actually works fine. However, I feel like this is a very clumsy implementation. The obvious problems are that the if/else tree will just grow larger and larger the more screens and events I define. There is also no error raised if I forget to connect or disconnect a certain event.
So. I am looking for a clever one-liner which connects ALL events of a screen to their handlers. My concept is as follows:

Every screen puts all of their events into a list called "AllActions". Example:
public Action[] AllActions = new Action[4] { ExitRequest, NewGameRequest, LoadRequest, SaveRequest };

The main logic gets a dictionary which informs about what event connects to where.


private Dictionary<string, Action> ActionToHandler= new Dictionary<string, Action>();

ActionToHandler.Add("ExitRequest", Exit);
ActionToHandler.Add("NewGameRequest", NewGame);
ActionToHandler.Add("LoadRequest", DeSerializeGame);
ActionToHandler.Add("SaveRequest", SerializeGame);


The "ConnectAllScreenEvents" method should turn into something like this;

   public void ConnectAllScreenEvents(Screen screen)
   {
       screen.ReturnRequest += ReturnFromScreen;

       for (int i = 0; i < screen.AllActions.Length; i++)
       {
           string actionName = screen.AllActions[i].ToString();
           Action handler = ActionToSlot[actionName];
           screen.AllActions[i] += handler;
       }
}

It doesn't work, though. The Actions are all null inside the "ConnectAllScreenEvents" method. I think this can work, but I just can't figure out the right C# syntax for this. All advice welcome.
Edit: Ok, I was able to solve the issue using the linked thread (Impossible to find if you don't know the term "reflection").Thank you. But I would still like to know, why did my own idea not work? Why can I not put actions in a list and loop through them?

Different things come to mind depending on your taste, in the end. For one, I could imagine a Visitor Pattern for registering and unregister. Or completely different: a message broker instead of eventing. Depends on with what you would be more comfortable.
